# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, unicode, xlwt

I have written the code below that provides the path to an Excel file that will be created with the XLWT module

```
master_path = r"C:\Users\nbt8ye8\Documents\Docs\Report Automation\KBE Reporting\Reports"
master_excel_file_raw = "KBE Master Data.xls"
master_excel_file = os.path.join(master_path, master_excel_file_raw)
```

Then later in the code I create the Excel file (which works without a problem) with the code below:

```
master_excel_wbook = xlwt.Workbook()
master_excel_wsheet = master_excel_wbook.add_sheet("All Data", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
master_excel_wbook.save(master_excel_file)
master_excel_wbook.save(tempfile.TemporaryFile())
```

However when I run the code it gives me the errors below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\nbt8ye8\workspace\Report Automation\import_data.py", line 1225, in <module>
createExcelFile()
File "C:\Users\nbt8ye8\workspace\Report Automation\import_data.py", line 1219, in createExcelFile
master_excel_wbook.save(master_excel_file)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 662, in save
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 637, in get_biff_data
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 599, in __sst_rec
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 76, in get_biff_record
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 91, in _add_to_sst
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xlwt\UnicodeUtils.py", line 50, in upack2
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I have tried encoding and decoding the strings and so far it has not worked but it is also highly likely I did not do it correctly. Any help would be greatly apprecieated. Thank you!

Comment: Got to love these errors. Do you want to preserve the original content as  best as possible? or can some of the unicode characters be replaced or ignored [skipped].

Comment: That is a good quesiton, if I just need the string to be the path to an Excel file on a Windows system can other unicode characters just be ignored? Thank you.

Comment: I believe the issue is not with the file path string that you are using. It is most likely a unicode character contained in the data that you are adding to the worksheet. Can you check that the data contained in the excel file you are creating does not contain unicode characters?

Comment: have you tried `master_excel_wbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")`?

Comment: @RyanG, thank you for that! That was the problem. It seems there was unicode data in the Excel file. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

@RyanG was correct, this error was thrown because there was unicode data in my Excel file. Once I modified the Excel file to remove the unicode data the problem was resolved. Thanks again.